# How should I chose which way to support multiple screens?

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have application completed that I have been testing on my Nexus 10. I have read through the different options for supporting different screen sizes on the Android website. I have made my layouts in Relative Layout. I'm uneasy to make different layouts for each screen size because I have so many, i'm worried about file space, because that is already a number I have trying to keep down. Is using Linear Layout with weights the best option? What should I do? I only need to support 4 types of tablets.

Comment: Size shouldn't be your concern its merely a couple of kb per file.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I don't think there is any better way than just doing the work and building the extra layouts you need.

If file size is really going to be an issue you should consider using a multiple apk approach.

This from the developers website:

"Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted to different device configurations. Each APK is a complete and independent version of your application, but they share the same application listing on Google Play and must share the same package name and be signed with the same release key. This feature is useful for cases in which your application cannot reach all desired devices with a single APK.

Android-powered devices may differ in several ways and it's important to the success of your application that you make it available to as many devices as possible. Android applications usually run on most compatible devices with a single APK, by supplying alternative resources for different configurations (for example, different layouts for different screen sizes) and the Android system selects the appropriate resources for the device at runtime. In a few cases, however, a single APK is unable to support all device configurations, because alternative resources make the APK file too big (greater than 50MB) or other technical challenges prevent a single APK from working on all devices."

see:  http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

Comment: I think I may just have to make the extra layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If your "tablet types/brand/version" doesn't change and you have all of them, go head and test, you might just need to create new file for specific layouts/custom views.